# How can I plot Frequency by DATE? Issues with table

Tags: r, date, ggplot2, time

I have a table

```
    library(RISmed)
search_topic <- "BID"
search_query <- EUtilsSummary(search_topic, mindate = 2016, maxdate=2018)
summary(search_query)
QueryId(search_query)
records <- EUtilsGet(search_query)
y <- data.frame(cbind("year"= YearPubmed(records), "month"= MonthPubmed(records)))
date()
count<-table(y)
count

month
year    1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12
  2016 49 54 49 59 45 54 43 44 40 47 42 42
  2017 52 35 52 48 30 37 43 42 25  0  0  0
```

I created a data frame with counts, but once I try make it into a as.Date, transforms to NA.

I want to plot by date, I can get the day as well but not that important to me.
But I keep getting error. That a character string is not ambiguous format.
Something like this:

[Graph of Input(BID)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8KCYe.png)

I cant seem to do this.

I want to plot the frequency over time(last 2 years).

This is inside a shiny app that I have made, but the output is killing me.

Any suggestions ?

I appreciate any feedback.

Comment: Can you be more specific about your expected output (e.g. post an example)?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
library(RISmed)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
search_topic <- "BID"
search_query <- EUtilsSummary(search_topic, mindate = 2016, maxdate=2018)
summary(search_query)
QueryId(search_query)
records <- EUtilsGet(search_query)
y <- data.frame(cbind("year"= YearPubmed(records), "month"= MonthPubmed(records)))
date()
count<-table(y)
count

y$date <- as.Date(strptime(paste(y$year, y$month, "01", sep="-"), "%Y-%m-%d", tz = "UTC"), origin="1970-01-01")

y %>% group_by(date) %>% summarise(n.citation = length(date)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=date, y = n.citation)) + geom_point()][1]][1]
```

[image]

HTH

James

Comment: Hello, James.
Thank you so much, that was quick. I really appreciate.

Comment: @FilipeRigueiro if this answer was helpful to you, consider accepting it (check mark to the left).

Answer (score 1):

Starting with a `table`

```
tbl <- structure(c(49L, 52L, 54L, 35L, 49L, 52L, 59L, 48L, 45L, 30L, 
54L, 37L, 43L, 43L, 44L, 42L, 40L, 25L, 47L, 0L, 42L, 0L, 42L, 
0L), .Dim = c(2L, 12L), .Dimnames = structure(list(Year = c("2016", 
"2017"), variable = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", 
"9", "10", "11", "12")), .Names = c("Year", "variable")), class = c("xtabs", 
"table"), call = xtabs(formula = value ~ Year + variable, data = melted))
```

You can make the combination of `Year-Months`

```
Combs <- expand.grid(attributes(tbl)$dimnames$Year, attributes(tbl)$dimnames$variable)

# or you can use
# Combs <- expand.grid(c("2016","2017"), 1:12))

library(lubridate)
preDates <- apply(Combs, 1, function(x) paste0(x, collapse="-"))
sortedDates <- sort(parse_date_time(preDates, "y-m"))

newdf <- data.frame(Date = sortedDates, Value = c(tbl))
plot(Value ~ Date, data=newdf)
```

Comment: Thank you very much guys(and girls). I manage to plot the frequency beautifully. The app is up and running thanks to you. This will help me a lot. 
I just now need to know how to create a another one that will get all the 25 top inputs and plot them together by selection. But thats for another time.